# Calculated fields - sum of products

Tags: excel, calculated-field

I tried to calculate a sum of a product (in the example: quantity product price), so If I sum all the products, I get a value (the dynamic table in the upper side). But when I enter the calculated field quantity*product, Excel got a sum of all the quantity product the sum of all the prices.
How can I solve that?
[In this image, I have a table with the data that I want to show through a pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTUVV.png)

[If a put the column Total in the Value section, i get the sum of all the Total values, considering Total as a multiply of quantity and price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub4Am.png)

[In this table, I put the calculate field quantity*price to get the sum, but I got the sum of quantity multiply the sum of price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqVf1.png)

[The calculate field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPxRa.png)

Comment: "Excel got a sum of all the quantity product the sum of all the prices." - What?

Comment: It might help if you would show the formula you tried, tell us in which cell of which table you tried it, and clarify which of your two pictures is "the dynamic table in the upper side". Please edit your question to include all relevant information, such as what your formula does and what's your expectation..

Comment: I see what you're asking now. Unfortunately this is just how Excel works with calculated fields. Why don't you just stick with the `Total` column in the source table?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've done this:

[image: bad]

But you should have done this:

[image: good]

To sum the individual months you can do this:

[image: month1]

Or even this:

[image: month2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I update the main post to clarify my problem.